# Formal Deduction -

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

> Prove by formal deduction that Paul is the son of John from the
>      following premises:

Premises

1. John is the father of Paul.
2. Paul is not the daughter of John.
3. A child is either a son or a daughter.

Predicates && Constants && Domain:

- Domain: The set of all people
- $F(x,y)$: $x$ is the father of $y$.
- $S(x,y)$: $x$ is the son of $y$.
- $D(x,y)$: $x$ is the daughter of $y$.
- $J$: John
- $P$: Paul

Hint: the formal proof uses the

- disjunctive syllogism: ($A \lor B, \lnot A \vdash B$)
- ($∀−$), universal instantiation.

What I am confused in this problem is,
for the 3rd premise, I set as
A child is either a son or a daughter: $\forall x \exists y(S(x,y) \lor D(x,y))$

Is this the correct interpretation of the English sentence?
Or $\forall x \forall y(S(x,y) \lor D(x,y))$?

If I have $\forall x\forall y(S(x,y) \lor D(x,y))$, I could easily prove.

Please, help. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to use the father relation: $(\forall\,x)(\forall\,y)[\text{Father}(x,y)\implies S(y,x)\lor D(y,x)]$.

Comment: This is a really really bad logic problem.  It expects you to make a lot of a-posteriori assumptions not given as premises.  Further it keeps using the word "the" like "the father of X" but presents father/etc as relations instead of functions, making the assumption of uniqueness ambiguous.  If you are learning logic from this source, I strongly suggest looking somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKeister I solved it!

Comment: @DanielV thanks for pointing out. But this is my school :(

Comment: @VioletOlive You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Using Adrian Keister's symbolization of the third premise, here is a formal proof:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/